# Navigation problems in intellij (Ctrl+B, Ctrl+Alt+B is not working to access method declartions/implementations)

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation

I have recently shifted from eclipse to intellij.

When I opened my projects in intellij, I am not able to navigate like in Eclipse.

I checked my keymap, its been configured like below

[image]

But still I can't access the declarations or implementations of methods/ classes in my intellij.
When I click on a method (ctrl + B), there is a red popup saying '"Cannot find declaration to go to"

[image]

I have got Community Edition - 2019.3.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Just had to update indices. After importing project into intellij, a default process runs that updates all indices. Mine was paused because of another background process. Just had to restart it.